# Checking continuity result given a probability space and metric

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose we have a probability space ($\Omega$, $F$, $P$) is a probability space and $A_1,A_2 \in F$ and define the distance $d:F \times F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $d(A_1,A_2) = P((A_1-A_2) \cup (A_2-A_1))$ then we want to show that if $A_n,A \in F$ and $d(A_n,A) \rightarrow 0$ then $\int_{A_n}XdP \rightarrow \int_AXdP.$

My thinking is that we need $A_n \rightarrow A$ then $d(A_n,A) \rightarrow 0$ than this applies that $P((A_1-A_2) \cup (A_2-A_1))$ $\rightarrow 0$ but I don't know how to prove the implication from knowing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is assumed to be integrable throughout.

First, show that if $S_n$ is a sequence with $\mathbb{P}(S_n)\to 0$ and $X$ is integrable, then $\int_{S_n} X \to 0$. I suggest doing this by examining the sets
$$
U_n = \{\omega\in\Omega: |X(\omega)|> n\}.
$$
Note that $\mathbb{P}(U_n)\to 0$ and $\int_{U_n} |X| \to 0$. (Why?) Then show that if $\mathbb{P}(S_n) < \mathbb{P}(U_{n'})$, then $\int_{S_n} |X| \le \int_{U_n'} |X|$. It will then follow that $\int_{S_n} X \to 0$.

Next observe
$$
\int_A X - \int_{A_n} X = \int_{A-A_n} X - \int_{A_n-A} X.
$$
The lemma above should apply to both summands here, assuming $d(A,A_n)\to 0$.